# Oracle JSON_TABLE - result of query cannot be filled in Varchar(4000)

Tags: sql, json, oracle, oracle11g

I have a question about oracle JSON_TABLE. I'm consulting a JSON that's in a CLOB Column () in a table. Here is my query:

```
select b.jsonvalue
from TB_ABC a, 
json_table(a.json_value, '$[*]' 
columns(
          targett VARCHAR2 PATH '$.target',
          jsonvalue varchar2(4000) FORMAT JSON PATH '$.targetData[*]',
          NESTED PATH '$.targetData[*]' COLUMNS(
            typee VARCHAR2 PATH '$.type'
          )
      )
  ) b
```

But the value returned to "jsonvalue" is greater than 4000 characters, so it can't be filled in Varchar2.

I have already tried to change the data type of the "jsonvalue" to CLOB, but JSON_TABLE seems that not support this data type.

What can I do to solve this?

Comment: According (documentation)[http://docs.oracle.com/database/121/SQLRF/functions093.htm#SQLRF56707] you can have only `NUMBER` or `VARCHAR2`, i.e. limited to 4000, resp. 32767 characters.  Is `jsonvalue` really a single value or can you further split it?

Comment: It's a single value that I'll parse to Java Object further.

Answer (score 0):

Have you enabled extended VARCHAR semantics  (AKA VARCHAR2(32k)..

This would let you return up to 32k of data. Do you really have a value with more than 32K of data...

Comment: Hello Mark Yes, I have more than 32K of data

Answer (score 0):

in the statement you just specify VARCHAR2 without any length information. This will internally be interpreted as a VARCHAR2(4000) irregardless of the MAX_STRING setting.
Instead of VARCHAR2 use VARCHAR2(32767) if you want the max length.

starting with 12.2 you can also use CLOB or BLOB as columns data type for values > 32767.